# How to use last-child selector on table row element

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I am trying to remove a style on the last element of my table row however everything I have tried removes the styles from all of the elements. I have tried `last-child` and `last-of-type` to no prevail.

Here is what the table body looks like

```
<tr v-for="(status, index) in workflow.statuses" :key="index">
   <th scope="row" class="status-th"><div class="status-order"></div> {{ index + 1 }}</th>
   <td>{{ status.status }}</td>
   <td class="text-center"><i class="fas fa-check text-primary"></i></td>
</tr>
```

I am using a nested div with the class of `.status-order` to make some custom content. The last div with the class of `.status-order` I would like to remove the custom content with the `last-child:after` selector. However when I attempt to apply the selector it removes it from all of the table rows. Here is the css(scss)

```
.status-order {
  position: relative;
  right: 8px;

  &:before{
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #0077ff;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding-right: 5px;
  }

  &:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: -2;
    height: 50px;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
  }

}
```

This is what the css creates on the table
[image]

I have tried adding the following to remove the last child content but like I said it removes all of them

```
&:last-child:after {
   border-right: transparent;
}
```

Comment: `&:last-of-type:after` does not work either?

Comment: `status-order` will always be the last-child, as it is the first-child too. You should target its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will helps you. please check below example.

```css
.custome-table th,
 .custome-table td {
  padding: 10px;
 }
 .status-order {
   position: relative;
   right: 8px;
 }
 .status-order:after {
     content: " ";
     position: absolute;
     left: 10px;
     z-index: -2;
     height: 40px;
     border-right: 5px solid black;
     top: -10px;
 }
 .status-order:before {
   content: " ";
     position: absolute;
     height: 25px;
     width: 25px;
     background-color: #0077ff;
     z-index: -1;
     border-radius: 50%;
     padding-right: 5px;
 }
 .custome-table tr:last-child .status-order:after {
  border-color: transparent;
 }
```

```html
<table class="custome-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
 <tr v-for="(status, index) in workflow.statuses" :key="index">
    <th scope="row" class="status-th"><div class="status-order"></div> {{ index + 1 }}</th>
    <td>{{ status.status }}</td>
    <td class="text-center"><i class="fas fa-check text-primary"></i></td>
 </tr>
 <tr v-for="(status, index) in workflow.statuses" :key="index">
    <th scope="row" class="status-th"><div class="status-order"></div> {{ index + 1 }}</th>
    <td>{{ status.status }}</td>
    <td class="text-center"><i class="fas fa-check text-primary"></i></td>
 </tr>
 <tr v-for="(status, index) in workflow.statuses" :key="index">
    <th scope="row" class="status-th"><div class="status-order"></div> {{ index + 1 }}</th>
    <td>{{ status.status }}</td>
    <td class="text-center"><i class="fas fa-check text-primary"></i></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I used the last part of your css, to target the last-child. ` table tr:last-child .status-order:after {
  border-color: transparent;
 }` feel free to post that as an answer and I will select it as the answer. I also change `.custom-table` to just the `table` element